# Dock all new conversation for lync

Tags: lync-2013

I'm using lync SDK 2013 and I'm currently trying to dock conversations.
Right now, i can dock conversation if I know the sip (sip writted Inside the code).
But i'd like to know if it's possible to dock ALL new conversation, regardless of how i started it (with a contact list for example)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible through LyncAutomation. I have done it for Lync meetings. The Lync Meetings display an alert message on the bottom right of Window. You can "Accept" the meeting through automation and then dock the Lync window to your own UI.